# Find the probability that the team Roaster contains both Ted and Vanessa

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGejl.jpg)A school science fair team will consist of two male students two female students and one "alternate". The alternate can be of either sex. There are four males(including Ted) and five females (including Vanessa) trying out for the team. A team Roster is list of five chosen , without mention of which one of the five will be the alternate. If the five students are chosen randomly from among the nine trying out .Find the probability that the team Roster contains both Ted and Vanessa.

Comment: Please try to improve the language. This phrase does not make sense to me: "on 'alternate' the alternate either be sex." So I am not 100% sure what the problem is.

Comment: What have you done in your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: @thanassis...i added photo of the problem

Comment: Seems like the problem description does not have enough information to get an answer. In particular "five students are chosen randomly from among the nine" is vague. We need to know what is the process of choosing.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*

Favorable ways will include Ted, Vanessa plus either two males, one female or vice versa.

Total ways will include either $3$ males, $2$ females, or vice versa.

Can you now proceed ?